# ELMAH notification emails send fine via SMTP but won't save to local folder

Tags: c#, email, error-handling, web-config, elmah

I have ELMAH working nicely and it is configured to send me an email when an exception is thrown. I've changed my web.config `mailSettings` tag's child elements to try and save the emails to a local folder but it doesn't seem to be saving anything. Here's the change:

```
<system.net>
    <!--Saving emails sent to local machine rather than actually sending them-->
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\TestEmails"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: Try changing the folder to your "APP_DATA" folder, if it works it's because the APP_DATA folder has the necessary folder access permissions by default.

Comment: Did you try restarting your app in IIS after making the change? I'd try @Pete's suggestion first though.

Comment: Tried the App_Data folder, no joy. I'd been restarting the app between attempts but manually killed IIS Express to be sure, still no luck. Thanks though.

Comment: I've just written a quick method that fires an email programmatically and it saves to my App_Data folder so I'm thinking this is ELMAH-related.